# Always run a command after another command

Tags: command-line, zsh, ls

With `zsh` (and `oh-my-zsh`), is it possible to always run a command after a certain other command? I want to always run an `ls` after `cd`ing to a directory, rather than running `cd example; ls` every time.

I have tried:

```
function cd {
  cd $1
  ls
}
```

But it seems to exit `zsh` when run, without any output (stack overflow?). Changing the name of the function makes it work as intended, however I would rather still use the `cd` command.

```
alias cd='cd $1;ls'
```

Lists the specified directory, but doesn't actually change the working directory.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: The `&&` command might be useful. (e.g. `alias cd='cd $1;ls && ls`).

Comment: I don't think aliases are suitable for this kind of thing, use a function instead.

Comment: @Hennes that appears to `ls` the current directory and the new one, but still doesn't move the actual shell.

Comment: Ah. Not logged into a zsh atm, but `&& ls $1` ?

Comment: @evilsoup I agree, the function in my post when renamed works. How can I make it work while still called cd?

Comment: @Hennes exactly the same output.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49711/34494 (can't be bothered to write it up as an answer, someone else should feel free).

Answer (score 13):

Although you already solved you problem yourself, I want to elaborate a little bit.

### Why your alias does not work:

@evilsoup already hinted at it, but to state it clearly: Aliases (in *zsh* and *bash*) are not able to take arguments (whereas in *csh* they can). Think of it as a simple string replacement. Hence with `alias cd='cd $1;ls'` defined, the command `cd foo` expands to `cd ; ls foo` because `$1` is empty (not defines in this context) and you see the content of `foo/` but the shell does `cd` into into the *current* directory (no argument after `cd`).

### Why your function as in the question does not work:

You define a function `cd`, which itself calls `cd`. So you end up in an infinite loop. The current zsh version (5.0.2) doesn't segfault, but gives an error:

```
cd:1: maximum nested function level reached
```

The solution is to use `builtin cd` inside your function `cd` -- as you already worked out yourself.

### Why your function (from [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20413/33390)) can be improved

You are redefining the `cd` function. That works fine, if you call it explicitly. But zsh offers the `AUTO_CD` option (to be set with `setopt AUTO_CD`):

> If  a  command  is issued that can't be executed as a normal command,
>   and the command is the name of a directory, perform
>                 the cd command to that directory.

That means you can change to `/var` by simply typing `/var` instead of `cd /var`. In this case your `cd` function isn't called and you didn't see the content of `/var` automatically.

[`pushd` and `popd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49711/33390) are other cases where a redefined `cd` command doesn't help.

### The ZSH way

[Stephane Chazelas on SE/UL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49711/33390) already gave the zsh-ish way, as pointed out by @evilsoup in the comments: Do not redefine `cd`, but use the hook function `chpwd()`, which is there for exactly that reason:

> `chpwd`  Executed whenever the current working directory is changed.

So just add

```
function chpwd() {
  ls
}
```

to your `~/.zshrc`. (A short form of that is `chpwd() ls` as given in the linked answer.)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49711/34494) post on Unix/Linux solved it for me:

```
function cd {
  builtin cd "$@" && ls -F
}
```

It's about bash, but works for me in zsh.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't define `chpwd()` function directly.**

In ZSH, there is hook `chpwd` designed to run commands after directory is changed.

Don't define `chpwd()` function directly. It will override other functions hooked on `chpwd`. The **canonical** way is to define a function and add it into hook `chpwd`, which make it coexist with other functions into hook `chpwd`.

```bsh
# Hook onto `chpwd` in the right way
# with the official util add-zsh-hook

# wrap command `ls` into a function
_ls_on_cwd_change() {
  command ls;
}

# load add-zsh-hook if it's not available yet
(( $+functions[add-zsh-hook] )) || autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

# hook _ls_on_cwd_change onto `chpwd`
add-zsh-hook chpwd _ls_on_cwd_change

# Additional info
# list existing hook functions
add-zsh-hook -L
# or
add-zsh-hook -L chpwd
```